# power window relay Pontiac Grandville 1971

Tags: pontiac, power-windows

Can you tell me where the location of the power window relay is situated in a 1971 Pontiac Grandville?

Thanks, Hans

Comment: I only have a Chevy book which covers that year. It states about relays: "*The electrical protection devices are located in the convenience center, which is a swing down unit located under the instrument panel. All units are serviced by plug-in replacements.*" Not much help ... but maybe?